# Import 5gb sql file into MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.6, import, mysql-8.0

i have exported sql file using mysql dump from a database and i am trying to import this big 5gb file into anohter mysql database. I am using mysql -u username -p -h hostname <file.sql command however getting error after some time.

error :  ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 6950: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

i have added max_allowed_packet =1g and connect_timeout however still not able to import the big file.

If any one can share something that would be great :)

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout";`  How long did it run before timing out?

Answer (score 0):

i increased connect_timeout to 120 and it helped to import big file